# PHP echo add spaces

Tags: php, html

How do I get some empty spaces after the current logged in user first name is displayed? Just need a few spaces because it's running into something else.

```
<?php 

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

echo '<span class="white-text">Welcome, &nbsp;' .$current_user->user_firstname     .       "</span>\n";}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way would be not to add more spaces, but add a margin:

```
<span class="white-text" style="margin-right: 5em;">
```

Change `5em` to some other number to change the amount of space.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<span class="white-text">Welcome, &nbsp;' .$current_user->user_firstname . "  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span>\n";
```

each &nbsp; is a "non-breaking space"

Comment: it's a `Non-breaking space` not a `non-blank space`

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because the extra spaces are ignored, this is normal. Only the first space character will be outputted, if you want more, use `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space).

You can also put a margin on the text with CSS:

```
span.white-text {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been faced with a similar problem and after much trial and error found that this works for my code line, inserting a space between First Name and Surname - so something similar may well work for yours...

```
<option value=<?php echo $row ["First_Name"], "&nbsp;", $row["Surname"] ; ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<span class='white-text'>Welcome," . " " .$current_user->user_firstname."</span>\n";
```

Comment: remove `&nbsp;` just use `" "`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td>" . $info['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['refid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['username'] . "</td>";
```